# Optimize MySQL inserts in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, performance, prepared-statement

My C++ code in order to write in the database a vector of items is the following:

```
void DatabaseManager::insertItems(vector<DbEntry>& items) {

    shared_ptr<MySQLConnection> connection = nullptr;

    try {


        connection = connections_->borrow();

        auto statement = shared_ptr<Statement>(connection->sql_connection_->createStatement());

        unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt(connection->sql_connection_->prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO my_table (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"));

        for (auto& item : items) {

            pstmt->setInt64(1, item.get_a());                 
            pstmt->setUInt(2, item.get_b());  
            pstmt->setUInt(3, item.get_c());              
            pstmt->setInt(4, item.get_d());        
            pstmt->setString(5, item.get_e());  

            pstmt->executeUpdate();
            unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> rs(statement->executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()") );

            uint64_t id {0};
            if (rs->next()) {
                id = rs->getUInt64(1);
            }

            rs->close();
            item.set_id(id);

        }

        connections_->unborrow(connection);

    } catch (SQLException &e) {

       //code rollbacks here 

    }

}
```

I would like to make this code snippet go faster but I don't know how. The borrow and unborrow functions that are not shown here, return a connection from a std::deque. Let's consider them "fast".

This insert is executed many times (with different values) and I was wondering if this part can be optimized further. If yes, how? The SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID is needed, we need to get the row id (which is an AUTO_INCREMENT field).

Comment: What kind of performance problems are you experiencing? How many inserts are you doing and how long does it take? Are you sure this isn't a server tuning issue?

Comment: without the insert call I have 3K req per second. With the insert I have 200 requests per second.

Comment: It's highly probable that your database server is the bottleneck here. Have you tuned it at all? MySQL's defaults are trash. In particular, check your [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) and give it at least 2GB if not more if you can spare it. I'm also presuming you're using InnoDB because it's 2019, but if you're using MyISAM for some reason there's different tuning parameters.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing with `id`.  If nothing, then there is a much faster way to do a batch of inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, tuning MySQL insert performance is a [large topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/118504/how-to-improve-mysql-insert-and-update-performance) with no simple one-size-fits-all answer.

Looking at the code I would suggest to try MySQL multiple-row [inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), this should significantly improve performance:

`INSERT INTO my_table (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?) ...` (all the way up to `max_allowed_packet`, by default 1 MB)

Using prepared statements in this case can become cumbersome, so use a regular query with [escaped](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) values instead. With MySQL, regular queries are also marginally faster than prepared statements.

[`mysql_insert_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) will return the ID of the first inserted row, from that you can compute the remaining IDs (the generated ID's are sequential).

Comment: Hi @rustyx, by regular queries you mean an "std::string" ready with the INSERT STATEMENT? Really is this faster than the prepared statement? Why?

Comment: MySQL doesn't really cache prepared statements like some other DBs do. It binds the values, and *then* parses the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running with `autocommit=ON`.  (Check that `VARIABLE`.)

It would be faster to do a `START TRANSACTION` *before* the loop, and a `COMMIT` afterwards.